# How to create a folder with a dot in the name using std::filesystem?

Tags: c++, windows, filesystems

There was a need to create a Windows directory with the name ".data". But when trying to create this path via std::filesystem:create_directory / create_directories, a folder is created in the directory above with an unclear name:

```
E:\n¬6Љ
```

> P.S in the documentation for std::filesystem i found: ***dot: the file name consisting of a single dot character . is a directory name that refers to the current directory***

My code:

```
ifstream Myfile;
string line;
char patht[MAX_PATH];
Myfile.open("dirs.lists");
if (Myfile.is_open())
{
    while (!Myfile.eof())
    {
        while (std::getline(Myfile, line))
        {
            sprintf(patht, "E:\\game\\%s", line);
            std::filesystem::create_directories(patht);
        }
    }
}
```

and dirs.lists contain:

```
game\\modloader\\.data
game\\modloader\\.profiles
```

Comment: the documentation you found is for the folder called `.` but `.data` is a different folder

Comment: Which compiler and version?

Comment: Well, when I correct the typos in your code (missing `:` and `;`) and change to a drive/folder that exists on my PC, I get the expected `.data` subfolder created. Maybe there is some hidden/weird character(s) in your *actual* code: the code you posted here won't even compile, let alone run.

Comment: Also, does your `Some_Path` already exist? Pretty sure you can't create the entire chain to your `.data` in one call.

Comment: @AlanBirtles C++17 ( visual studio 2022)

Comment: @AdrianMole yeah, exists

Comment: @AdrianMole This is not literally executable code, it was written just to show what function I use.

Comment: And if you run this code does it reproduce your problem? Please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I`m sorry, I added a real example code.

Comment: The outer `while (!Myfile.eof())`  loop can be removed. The `while (std::getline(Myfile, line)) {}` loop will properly read up to the last line of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the address of `line` to `sprintf`, not a string!

Try `sprintf(patht, "E:\\game\\%s", line.c_str());`

Comment: Thank you it helped me, I am very ashamed of such a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a `std::string` to `sprintf`, you need to add `c_str()`.

There is no reason to use `sprintf` in the first place, use `std::filesystem::path`:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::ifstream Myfile("dirs.lists");
  std::string line;
  std::filesystem::path root = "E:\\game";
  while (std::getline(Myfile, line))
  {
    std::filesystem::create_directories(root / line);
  }
}
```